# How to compare 2 excel file online

Tags: c++, vba

currently i have one Excel template  that content a lots of the VBA code for compare 2 excel file,but did have any idea to pull it into website for using online?

For example the excel template are providing browse 2 excel file and after browse 2 excel into website and it will compare and provide a after compare file for download or maybe showing summary in website.

## is that possible pull the VBA code into website for online compare?

Thanks and regards,

kind1212

Comment: Hello, VBA runs in Excel. You can't (practically) run an Excel on a webserver. So no, no practical way to run a VBA code on a website. You will have to rewrite the comparison logic in another programming language, C#, java, whatever floats your boat. Use an SDK to manipulate Excel files (for example Office Open XML SDK).

Comment: @vacip if that possible direct put my template excel file on website then direct browser another compare file for comparing? or just only the way is rewrite the code in other language?thanks.

Comment: Hello, it is quite hard to understand what you are trying to say... No, there is no way to run VBA for Office outside Office (ok this is not literally true, but in your case it is true). So yes, the only way is to rewrite the code and rethink the logic.